# converting InputStream to BufferedImage returns null

Tags: java, blob

I am writing a code to retrieve multiple 'blob' images from database and concatenate them together,
below is the code

```
ResultSet images = pst.executeQuery();
byte[] imageData = null;
Blob blob = null;
int blobLength = 0;
List<BufferedImage> list = new LinkedList();

while (images.next()) {                                 
    blob = ((OracleResultSet) images).getBLOB(2);
    blobLength = (int) blob.length();
    imageData = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);   
    list.add(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)));
}
```

the problem is that the list is always null, 
although the variable 'imageData' contains the image (I cheked it).
that mean , java couldn't convert the ByteArrayInputStream to BufferedImage,, why??!!

Comment: What is the format of that image? JPEG, PNG, raw...?

Comment: it is JPEG, does the type make any difference?

Comment: Sure it does... ImageIO can't read some odd types without a plugin. It uses the image header to determine which algorithm should be used to decode the image, so raw images (without a header) can generate problems.

Comment: assuming that the image type is one of the odd types , how can i get the plugins?

Comment: First of all, you really need to know the type of the image you're handling. A good way to discover that is to save the `imageData` in your HDD and open it in one image editor.

Comment: And does it work if you read the `imageData` from your HDD, using FileInputStream? I'm trying to discover with your image is a valid one.

Comment: i can tell you the image is valid one, because i can get it in the browser when i execute the code below:
response.getOutputStream().write(imageData);

that mean it is valid as a byte data,
but when trying to convert it to bufferedimage, here come the problem!!

Comment: Browsers can handle more image types than ImageIO... My bet: your image doesn't have the headers needed for ImageIO to render it as a `BufferedImage`. You should try to debug it, for instance, inserting a JPEG from your digital camera in your database, just for testing.